# Props in React showing up as undefined when trying to use router on parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I am trying to render a list of child components (Conversationcards) by mapping through an array on my Conversationslist component. The render function on the parent looks like this:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Conversationslist component</h2>
                {this.state.conversations.map((item, index) => this.renderCard(item, index))}
            </div>
                );
            }
        }
```

Each object in the array is passed into a renderCard function which gathers the necessary information from state and renders the card with that information (fullObj) as a prop (conversationObj).

```
renderCard = (conversation, index) => {
                var conversationObj1 = conversation
                var fullObj = {}
                var participantsObj = this.state.participants.filter(participant => participant.conversationIndex == index)
                var listenersObj = this.state.listeners.filter(listener => listener.conversationIndex == index)
                fullObj = {conversation: conversationObj1, participants: participantsObj, listeners: listenersObj}
                    return(
                        // <Router>
                        //  <Link to="./Conversation">
                        //   <Conversationcard key= {index} reRenderCallback = {this.forceUpdate} conversationObj={fullObj}/>
                        //   </Link>
                        //   <Switch>
                        //    <Route path="/Conversation">
                        //     <Conversation conversationObj={fullObj}/>
                        //    </Route>
                        //   </Switch>
                        // </Router>
                        <Conversationcard key= {index} reRenderCallback = {this.forceUpdate} conversationObj={fullObj}/>
                    )
            }
```

It works, and the children can log and render the information passed as props. However, when I try to adjust something in the renderCard function on the parent (such as making the child component a clickable link which opens another component by uncommenting the lines in the renderCard return statement) I get the error that the props being passed to the child are undefined. It reads "TypeError: Cannot read property 'participants' of undefined" and points to every line in the child that tries to use props. Then, even if I undo the changes in the parent component rendering function, I get the same error while trying to run the same exact code which previously worked. I then have to comment out every line in the child which uses props, then I can uncomment them and it works again. In other words, when I make a breaking change on the parent, I cannot simply undo it by reverting to the previous code. Why do props continue to show up as undefined until I make the child stop trying to use them, then work again after reinserting them? Should I not be trying to pass props to child components if I want to use them as links?

Comment: you might want to share more code, ex. `Conversation` what's inside it? My suggestion, when you start, try not to mix `Component` and `renderComponent`. It's two different ways that might confuse u. Stick with Component at the beginning.